# Unable to see my textbox data in Datagrid by clicking button using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

[image]

Hi guys i have a problem since last week and i am unable to sort out the reason,the problem is i want my textboxes data to be display in a datagrid ,i am using WPF C# and pattern is MVVM.

My code in XAML is:

```
    <TextBox 
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Height="25"
            Foreground="Black"
            Opacity="0.8"
            Width="Auto"
            Text="{Binding VlanName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
            />



        <TextBox 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            Height="25"
            Foreground="Black"
            Opacity="0.8"
            Width="70"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Text="{Binding VlanID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
            />

 <Button Grid.Column="3"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="Add VLAN"
            Margin="10,5,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}"
            Command="{Binding AddVlan}" 

            />      

    <Button Grid.Column="3" 
            Grid.Row="2"
            Content="Remove VLAN"
            Margin="10,5,0,0"
            Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}"
            Width="100"
            Command="{Binding RemoveVlan}"
            />
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Height="200"
              Margin="10,10,0,0"
              Name="dg"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source=vlan}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"

              > 

      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="S.No"    Binding="{Binding Path=S_No}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN Name" Binding="{Binding Path=vname}"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN ID"      Binding="{Binding Path=vid}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="           IP" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VLAN Ports" Width="100"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

C# View model is :

```
 vlan = new ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass>();



    public string VlanName
        {
          get
          {
            return this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName;
          }
          set
          {
            if (String.Equals(this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName, value))
            {
              return;
            }
            this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("VlanName");
          }
        }
    public string VlanID
    {
      get
      {
        return this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName;
      }
      set
      {
        if (String.Equals(this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName, value))
        {
          return;
        }
        this.ConfigurationLibrary.ConfigLibraryVlanName = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("VlanID");
      }
    }
     public ICommand AddVlan
        {
          get
          {
            if (_addVlan == null)
              _addVlan = new RelayCommand(() => this.AddVlans());

            return _addVlan;
          }

        }

        public ICommand RemoveVlan
        {
          get
          {
            if (_removeVlan == null)
              _removeVlan = new RelayCommand(() => this.RemoveVlans());

            return _removeVlan;
          }

        }
        #endregion //ICommand region end

        void AddVlans()
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Add vlan");
          var serial = new VLANSPropertyClass();
          serial.S_No = vlan.Count + 1;
          serial.vname = VlanName;
          serial.vid = VlanID;
          vlan.Add(serial);
        }
```

Code in the VLAN method is not working i dont know why because i am able to see the line `Add vlan` which i wrote in Console but later code is not working i dont know the reason please help?

Comment: does the collection 'vlan' have a public getter on it?

Comment: yes...
 public ObservableCollection<VLANSPropertyClass> vlan { get; set; } ..
i forgot to paste in the above code.

Comment: I think there might be an issue in AddVlans() method!

Comment: Update code to show your `vlan` property - it needs public getter and to raise property changed.

Comment: I see a possible issue, but what does the DataGrid actually display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:
The issue was in my ItemSource in XAML. I changed `ItemsSource="{Binding Source=vlan}"` to  `ItemsSource="{Binding vlan}"` 
and it start displaying all the data in my Datagrid.

:)